# Connection with POS terminal

Tags: php, pos

I am using this library: https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php
With the first example

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/mike42/escpos-php/autoload.php';

use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;

$connector = new FilePrintConnector("php://stdout");
$printer = new Printer($connector);
$printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
$printer -> cut();
$printer -> close();
```

Nothing happens. When I dump the `$connector` I can see notice:

```
object(Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector)#2 
  (1) { ["fp":protected]=> resource(6) of type (stream) } 
Notice: Print connector was not finalized. Did you forget to close the printer? 
  in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\vendor\mike42\escpos-php\src\Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector.php on line 44
```

My terminal is connected via bluethooth. I am working on Windows 10.
How should I connect to it? What should be the passed parameter in `FilePrintConnector` constructor?

Comment: I think that you don't need to add the space after the variable, so `$printer -> action()` will be this `$printer->action()`

Comment: How exactly do you run that script? All examples show that you redirect everything the code does to a device stream. Additionally, the issue tracker tells you that a bluetooth connection is currently not supported

Comment: I am using XAMPP.

Comment: Are you sure your bluetooth connection is active when you try to print? Could it be the same issue as in here? https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/53 where the server doesn't have an X server which is needed for https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/issues/53

Comment: Going to check it right now! Thank you! Will give feedback as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

This function works for me:

```php
    <?php 
    require __DIR__ . '/autoload.php';
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
    use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;

    $nombre_impresora = "TERMICA";
    $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector($nombre_impresora);
    $printer = new Printer($connector);
    $printer->setJustification(Printer::JUSTIFY_CENTER);


    $printer->setTextSize(1, 2);
    $printer->text("escribe la primer linea");
    $printer->setTextSize(1, 1);
    $printer->feed();
    $printer->feed(5);
    $printer->cut();
    $printer->pulse();
    $printer->close();
    ?>
```